# SAS/SQL - find 3 or more occurences within a given timeframe

Tags: sql, date, sas, proc-sql, datastep

I have hundreds of thousands of rows of data (like the example below) which consists of account number and the dates of calls that were placed. I need to find all accounts where there were 3 or more calls placed within a 7 day period. So, for the data below it would return the rows for accounts 1111111 and 3333333.

```
account_number  call_date
1111111          1/1/2010
1111111          1/3/2010
1111111          1/3/2010
1111111          1/5/2010
2222222          1/10/2010
2222222          1/20/2010
3333333          1/7/2010
3333333          1/7/2010
3333333          1/7/2010
```

There's probably a simple solution but for some reason I'm drawing a blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is tricky in SAS.  I would use a data step with `retain`.

Comment: By "7 day period," do you mean "week of the year" or "any 7 consecutive days?"

Comment: Any 7 consecutive days. For example, if there was one call on 1/1/2010. then there would need to be 2 more calls within then next 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer using a `data step` and the `lag` function and a `by group`.

```
proc sort data=have;
by acc_nbr call_date;
run;

data want(drop=count);
set have;
by acc_nbr call_date;
d2 = lag2(call_date);
format d2 date9.;
if first.acc_nbr then count = 1;
if count < 3 then d2 = .;
count + 1;
diff = call_date - d2;
if diff <= 7 and diff ne . then output;
run;
```

All this is doing is using the `lag2` function, which returns the value of `call_date` from two records before the current record. Next, we say if it's the first account number then set `count = 1`. Next, we set the value `d2` to missing if the count is less than 3. This ensures that we don't pick up a date value from a separate `by group`. Last, we just check to make sure the difference between `call_date` and `d2` is less than or equal to 7 and output that record.

This will output duplicate account numbers if there are multiple cases where a customer made over 3 calls in a 7 day period more than once so if you want unique values you can use `proc sql, select distinct` or `proc sort nodupkey`.

Comment: This throws a "missing values generated" note to the log, which many people treat as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Below is what I think I would do:

**Input data.** For each `call_date`, calculate the date 7 days before.

```
data have;
    input account_number : $char20.
          call_date : mmddyy10.;
    date_7_days_before = intnx('DAY',call_date,-7);

datalines;
1111111 1/1/2010
1111111 1/3/2010
1111111 1/3/2010
1111111 1/5/2010
2222222 1/10/2010
2222222 1/20/2010
3333333 1/7/2010
3333333 1/7/2010
3333333 1/7/2010
;
run;
```

**Consolidate calls Intra-day.** Sum number of calls by day per account.

```
proc sql;
    create table consolidate_calls as
    select account_number,
           call_date,
           date_7_days_before,
           count(*) as calls
   from have
   group by account_number,
            call_date,
            date_7_days_before;
quit;
```

**Self join `consolidated_calls`.** If the `b.call_date` is within the date range of `a.date_7_days_before` and `a.call_date` then group together.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select a.account_number,
           a.call_date format=mmddyy10.,
           a.calls as calls_that_day,
           sum(b.calls) as calls_last_7_days /*Number of calls on, or within 7 days of, the call_date*/
    from consolidate_calls as a
    left join consolidate_calls as b
    on a.account_number = b.account_number
    and b.call_date <= a.call_date 
    and b.call_date >= a.date_7_days_before
    group by a.account_number,
             a.call_date,
             a.calls
    ;
quit;
```

The self-join methodology is a little hard to explain for me, but I believe this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it looks like the solution generates results properly.

**Preparing Data**

```
data a;
    input account_number call_date :mmddyy.;
    format call_date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
1 1/1/2010
1 1/3/2010
1 1/3/2010
1 1/5/2010
2 1/10/2010
2 1/20/2010
3 1/7/2010
3 1/7/2010
3 1/7/2010
;
run;
```

**Solution**

```
proc sql;
    select distinct a1.account_number
    from a a1, a a2, a a3
    where a1.account_number = a2.account_number 
        and a1.account_number = a3.account_number
        and a3.call_date > a2.call_date 
        and a2.call_date > a1.call_date 
        and a3.call_date < a1.call_date + 7;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @J_Lard's approach, you can use the `DIF` function to compute the difference between a variable and its lag. This simplifies the code a bit.  If account number is numeric, you can find the records of interest by testing `dif2(id)=0 and dif2(calldate)<=7`  That checks that the ID is the same as two records before and that calldate is within 7 days.  If account number is not numeric, could use `id=lag2(id) and dif2(calldate)<=7` .  Of course this assumes data have already been sorted.

Below code adds a _DONE Boolean, used to track whether an ID has already been output.

```
data want (keep=id);
  set have;
  by id;
  retain _done; *boolean to flag when an id has already been output;
  if first.id then _done=0;

  if _done=0 and dif2(id)=0 and dif2(calldate) <= 7 then do;
    output;
    _done=1;
  end;
run;
```